# ASP.NET MVC upload images to a model

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a little problem with adding images in ASP.NET MVC. I created a folder in my root folder named `/Images/Brands/` where I wanted to save images of my brand models.

This is my `Brand` model:

```
namespace AspProjectBootstrap.Models
{
    public class Brand
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public String ImagePath { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I saw some people saving the path in the models class as `ImagePath` then when needed get the full path to the images from the `ImagesPath`.

And this is my create brand function:

```
public ActionResult Create(Brand brand)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(brand.ImageFile.FileName);
    filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + filename+".png";
    brand.ImagePath = "~/Images/Brands/" + filename;
    filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), filename);
    brand.ImageFile.SaveAs(filename);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Brands.Add(brand);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(brand);
}
```

But I get an error.

If you have any idea how to solve this problem, or any other method to do this task.

Thank you in advance.

The error is:

[image]

The create `Create.cshtml` view is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: the images didn't add to the folder, and give me error brand.ImageFile.SaveAs(filename);

Comment: You said "But it give me an error back." - what did the error say?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException : 'La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.'

AspProjectBootstrap.Models.Brand.ImageFile.get retournée null.

Comment: [Edit] that into your question please. I recommend stepping through you code using a debugger to find where the null reference is.

Comment: in this line it throws the error : string filename = Path.GetFileName(brand.ImageFile.FileName);

Comment: @DaleK the null ref is in ImageFile.FileName

Answer (score 0):

Your Create method is accepting a serialized model, and while the model can contain a file data, chances are it is not resolving the name:

This should work:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageFile, new { type="file" })
```

This will ensure the resulting input is named so MVC will recognize it on the form submit or serializing the model.

If that isn't working the next thing to check is to put a breakpoint on `string filename = Path.GetFileName(brand.ImageFile.FileName);` and inspect which part is #null. Is `ImageFile` null or `ImageFile.FileName`?  You should also validate your code to check for nulls in case a form can be submitted without supplying a file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Create.cshtml view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

The solution was:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Brands", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```